# Setting a page link in the footer?

Tags: links, footer

What is the proper process for setting a page up with a link to it in the footer?

Currently, all my pages are in Appearance -> Menu...and of course displayed in the main menu.

However I want a batch of them to be in the footer.

I have decent HTML,CSS, PHP skills but new to WP.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Place a menu in the footer or one link?

Comment: In the footer I want one link...`about`...when you click it I want the page to be displayed in the same way it would if you clicked a menu item....you know in them main display area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What may be easier (if you don't necessarily want all the same menu items to appear in the footer) is to:

- Create a new menu, "Footer Menu" for example
- Add-in whatever links (pages) are needed there
- Add a widget (called Custom Menu) to a footer widget position (if your current theme supports it).

Let me know if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks...I have footer sections...can you send me a link to the plugin you are referring to.

Comment: I didn't mention a plugin. I mentioned adding a navigation menu widget to your (updated answer to the exact name). No plugin needed.

Comment: I have 4 footers...wonder why...wonder how I'm suppose to know which one to use.

Comment: Theme only supports one menu...don't know what that means either.

Comment: Thats what he said, you have to **create** a new menu in admin. Then add this menu (via Custom Menu widget) to the footer widget position.

Comment: As @MihaRekar mentioned, when your theme says it only supports "x menus" that just means it has pre-defined spots in the theme that you can assign the theme to. You're still free to create as many menus as you like and (what is most likely easiest in your case) is assign those menus to widget positions that are available throughout your theme.